# Problems passing array to function in C

Tags: c, arrays, buffer

I've got a buffer declared as

```
uint8_t buffer[1000];
```

This is loaded with data and then send to a function like so:

```
Send_Data(buffer);
```

The function is declared as:

```
void Send_Data(uint8_t data[])
```

but when I go into the function, the data array is empty.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: How do you check that the array is empty?

Comment: Are you sure the data is loaded correctly ?

Comment: What do you mean by empty? Can you show more code?

Comment: I can see the data by debugging. I have watch expressions set up for the buffer array and the data array. When in debug before calling the function, I can see data in the buffer, but when i enter the function, the data array just contains "".

Comment: Show the function that loads the data. This function might mess things up (memory corruption) that cause problems later.

Comment: chadianscot: first up, make sure you're stepped _into_ the function, not just to the function header. Some debuggers may need that before they show the data properly. Second, ensure you're watching the correct `data`, the one in the function, not one elsewhere like a global. Third, don't trust the debugger, actually print out a few elements to see what they are.

Comment: Maybe inside the function you see `""` because the first byte is `\0`?  This problem would be easier to help if OP showed data in `buffer`

Comment: "*... before calling the function, I can see data in the buffer, but when i enter the function, the data array just contains "".*" this intensly smells like a corrupted memory management. Consider running the program using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org)

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely doing something *else* wrong over and above what you've explained in the question. This code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void Send_Data(uint8_t data[]) {
    printf ("%d\n", data[0]);
}

int main (void) {
    uint8_t buffer[1000];
    buffer[1] = 0;

    buffer[0] = 65;
    Send_Data (buffer);

    buffer[0] = 66;
    Send_Data (buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

producing the output:

```
65
66
```

Since, as proven by the above program, it's quite possible to do what you're trying to do, and because there's not really enough information in your question to narrow the problem down further, the best we can do is generalities:

1. Check that you *are* truly populating the array before the function call.
2. Don't necessarily rely on a debugger to tell you the array inside the *function* is unpopulated: print some of them out to be certain.
3. Run the above program in exactly the same way and see what you get in the array inside the function. In particular, look to see if it's being treated as a C string for example (will show up as `"A"` and `"B"`).